# How to read multiple sub tags from xml limited which has recursive subtags?

Tags: c#, xml, xelement

I have an xml which has multiple tags. Example:

```
<code>
    <Value>abc</value>
    <F> T </F>
    <F> A </F>
    <code1>
        <Value>abc</value>
        <F> T </F>
    </code1>
</code>
```

I want to read  tags associated only with the first code i.e first two tags. But my program is reading  tag for code1 as well.

```
foreach (var item in  element.Descendants("F"))
    {
        flNodeText = flNodeText + Convert.ToString(item.Nodes().First());
    }
```

Element is the whole xml mentioned above.
How can i make it read only the first two tags.

The number of tags can vary.

Comment: Use `Elements` instead of `Descendants`? I think you probably need to provide a more complete example here. Where does `element` come from?

Comment: element is the whole xml mentioned in the question. Edited the question to say the same

Comment: As @CharlesMager said. Just use `element.Elements("F")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Elements` to only return the immediate children. You can also use `XElement.Value` to get the text contents of an element.

```
var values = element.Elements("F")
    .Select(x => x.Value);

var flNodeText = string.Concat(values);
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rxGzIQ).

Comment: Thank you! This did what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

In VB .Net this would be

```
    ' for testing
    Dim xe As XElement = <code>
                             <Value>abc</Value>
                             <F> T </F>
                             <F> A </F>
                             <code1>
                                 <Value>abc</Value>
                                 <F> Z </F>
                             </code1>
                         </code>

    'returns all <F> nodes of root only
    Dim ie As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = xe.<F>
    'returns all <F> nodes of code1 only
    ie = xe.<code1>.<F>
    'returns all <F> nodes
    ie = xe...<F>
```